# Can't use special characters in Rails app with Rubinius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, rubinius

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 with Rubinius 2.4.1, installed on OSX 10.10 with RVM.

But when I write in the rails console `puts 'é'`, for example, I'm getting the following list of hostile errors:

```
An exception occurred running bin/rails:

"\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)

Backtrace:

                 String#encode! at kernel/common/string.rb:946
                 IO(File)#write at kernel/common/io.rb:2401
           { } in IO(File)#puts at kernel/common/io.rb:1796
                     Array#each at kernel/bootstrap/array.rb:76
                  IO(File)#puts at kernel/common/io.rb:1780
      Pry::History#save_to_file at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/history.rb:106
                    Method#call at kernel/common/method.rb:71
         Pry::History#<< (push) at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/history.rb:50
                Pry#handle_line at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:267
                { } in Pry#eval at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:243
                      Proc#call at kernel/bootstrap/proc.rb:20
       { } in Kernel(Pry)#catch at kernel/common/throw_catch.rb:30
 Rubinius::ThrownValue.register at kernel/common/throw_catch.rb:8
              Kernel(Pry)#catch at kernel/common/throw_catch.rb:29
                { } in Pry#eval at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:242
                      Proc#call at kernel/bootstrap/proc.rb:20
       { } in Kernel(Pry)#catch at kernel/common/throw_catch.rb:30
 Rubinius::ThrownValue.register at kernel/common/throw_catch.rb:8
              Kernel(Pry)#catch at kernel/common/throw_catch.rb:29
                       Pry#eval at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:241
          { } in Pry::REPL#repl at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:77
         Kernel(Pry::REPL)#loop at kernel/common/kernel.rb:510
                 Pry::REPL#repl at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67
         { } in Pry::REPL#start at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38
                      Proc#call at kernel/bootstrap/proc.rb:20
Pry::InputLock#__with_ownership at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61
  Pry::InputLock#with_ownership at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79
                Pry::REPL#start at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38
                Pry::REPL.start at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:15
                      Pry.start at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169
           Rails::Console#start at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110
           Rails::Console.start at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9
   Rails::CommandsTasks#console at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68
Rails::CommandsTasks#run_command! at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39
              Object#__script__ at /Users/hassen/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17
   Rubinius::CodeLoader.require at kernel/common/code_loader.rb:247
         Kernel(Object)#require at kernel/common/kernel.rb:755
              Object#__script__ at bin/rails:4
Rubinius::CodeLoader#load_script at kernel/delta/code_loader.rb:66
Rubinius::CodeLoader.load_script at kernel/delta/code_loader.rb:152
        Rubinius::Loader#script at kernel/loader.rb:645
          Rubinius::Loader#main at kernel/loader.rb:799
```

It seems that there is a problem with *UTF_8* encoding, but didn't find a way to fix this. Do you have an idea? Thanks.